# Inserting audio element causes CSS bugs

Tags: javascript, ios, html, dom, html5-audio

When I insert an `audio` tag into my HTML, it screws up the page, causing backgrounds and random elements to disappear. Why is this happening?

```
<audio style="display: none; "></audio>
```

I make it invisible because I'm using it to play audio in the background. This is happening to me on my iphone 5, ios 6.1.

Comment: Unfortunately a fiddle won't work with this. It only fails when tested directly on the iPhone (not a simulator), and there isn't a lot that is relevant. This happens on any page when I try to insert an `<audio>` tag.

Comment: Does it also happen when you remove that style rule? How about if you supply a `src` attribute?

Comment: @KevinEnnis Yes and yes. When I tap/move the screen, the background and invisible elements show up as they should, but the initial load is buggy.

Comment: Hmm. Maybe try manually triggering a reflow on page load? You could do that just by accessing `document.body.offsetHeight`. Otherwise, maybe try adding the `<audio>` tag to the page after load, with JS. Probably just something you need to play around with. Or am I misunderstanding you? Does the audio tag exist in the HTML on load, or are you creating it with JS?

Comment: I was creating it with JS. My temporary solution is to include it in the HTML template for the view, but it's not ideal. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if we're having the same problem but I found your question while searching for an answer to mine.  I also tried using `display:none;` on my audio tag and it made my HTML go screwy.  I was trying to hide it because I was using custom controls for the play/pause btns and for some reason there was a huge gap in between my text and buttons, but only on my iPad.  Come to find out, the audio element has default dimensions, 30px by 200px, you can see this in Chrome's dev tools if you want.  And it was the default dimensions that were pushing my elements apart.

Anyways, if that's why you're trying to hide the audio element, set the height and width to 0 instead of using `display:none;`

```
audio {
height:0;
width:0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It's ridiculous that the `audio` element doesn't respect `display: none`.

Comment: @jsejcksn Web design is ridiculously hacky.